# Deleting the front element in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to write a function that deletes the front element of my linked list and sets the head pointer to the next element after the deleted one.

Here is my code:

```
void LinkedList::delete_front(){
    if(head != NULL){
            if(head->next != NULL){
                    ListNode *tmp = head;
                    delete head;
                    head = tmp->next;
            }
            else {delete head; head = NULL;}
    }
    size--;
}
```

And here are my class definitions:

```
class ListNode{

    public:
            Item data;
            ListNode *next;
};
class LinkedList{

    private:
            ListNode *head;
            int size;

    public:
            LinkedList();
            ~LinkedList(); 
            bool empty();
            void insert_front(Item i);
            void insert_back(Item i);
            void delete_front();
            void delete_back();
            void print();
};
```

Annddddd.....this is the problem, when running in valgrind this error pops up right before the first delete_front() call:

```
==4738== Invalid read of size 8
==4738==    at 0x400B3C: LinkedList::delete_front() (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
==4738==    by 0x400E59: main (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
==4738==  Address 0x5a03f98 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==4738==    at 0x4C2A4BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4738==    by 0x400B37: LinkedList::delete_front() (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
==4738==    by 0x400E59: main (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem here:

```
if(head->next != NULL){
    ListNode *tmp = head;
    delete head;
    head = tmp->next;
}
```

You assign temp to head, then delete head.  Then try to access it again.

Comment: Ok... It works but now I've run into another problem. If there is one element left in the list, it won't remove it...It's supposed to delete the element and then set head = null.

Comment: do an else statement.
`else { delete head; head = null; }`

Answer (score 2):

You are deleting the element and afterwards, you try to access it. It's these lines:

```
ListNode *tmp = head;
delete head;
head = tmp->next; // tmp was initialized to head, but head was just deleted!
```

which should read:

```
ListNode *tmp = head->next;
delete head;
head = tmp;
```

---

Update: I just realized that with the above, the whole method could become much easier:

```
void LinkedList::delete_front()
{
    if(head != NULL) {
        ListNode *tmp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = tmp;
        --size;
    }
}
```

should work for all cases. You don't have to check for `head->next == NULL` as the above handles it as well. It also fixes the bug in your code where you decrease `size` even if the list was empty my moving `--size` inside the `if(head != NULL)` block.

Note that this keeps your original semantics which is "if the list is empty, do nothing". This is usually not what you want, consider throwing an exception:

```
void LinkedList::delete_front()
{
    if(head == NULL) {
        throw std::runtime_exception( "LinkedList::delete_front() "
                                      "called with empty list" );
    }

    ListNode *tmp = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = tmp;
    --size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here:

```
                ListNode *tmp = head;
                delete head;
                head = tmp->next;
```

You set tmp to head, then delete head, then you use tmp. tmp is pointing to memory that you just deleted.

Instead, set tmp to head, set head to head->next, THEN delete tmp.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a smart pointer it will reduce to:

```
void LinkedList::delete_front() {
    if(head != NULL) {
        head = head->next;
        --size;
    }
}
```

Where:

```
class ListNode{
    public:
        Item data;
        unique_ptr<ListNode> next;
};

class LinkedList{
    private:
        unique_ptr<ListNode> head;
//.. etc
```

Also, I've fixed the bug where the size was decreasing even if `head` was `NULL`.

Comment: This is what I am using, but I have a question about memory usage in C++. Does `head = head->next` delete the previous head node or does it stay in the memory, simply inaccessible?

Comment: It will be deleted if you use a smart pointer, and nothing else points to it. Otherwise, yes you would have a memory leak.